# How to force reviews to appear on page load? trigger processReviews

Tags: magento2, blocks, ajax, review

I'm trying to make customer reviews appear on the PDP page without clicking on the reviews button. On reviews tab click, ajax request is being sent to the server and I want to send this request on page load, however I could not find the file where the click event is written. Any kind of help would appreciated

This is the js file: **vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/web/js/process-reviews.js**

[image]
This is the reviews tab, clicking on it triggers ajax request send and I want to do it on page load

```
($(document).ready(function ($) {}) - using jQuery for example)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to switch to that tab, a simple way to do it would be to use jquery's `.click()` function such that:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {$("#tabid").click();})
```

Comment: No I don't want to switch to that tab, I simply want to send ajax request

Comment: Do you want to send it on page load or when the tab is clicked?